# CheckBox default to disabled in TreeTableView

Tags: java, javafx

I do not know why checkbox one of the columns are set to disable, although by. code with this page.

http://o7planning.org/en/11149/javafx-treetableview-tutorial#a3985429

That's my result:: [https://zapodaj.net/e7ba7de8ec222.png.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ0OI.png) There is no possibility of their selection.

```
    TreeTableColumn<MessageOnTable, Boolean> deleteCol
                = new TreeTableColumn<MessageOnTable, Boolean>("Delete");
deleteCol.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<MessageOnTable, Boolean>("delete"));

        deleteCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<MessageOnTable, Boolean>, //
                        ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<MessageOnTable, Boolean> param) {
                TreeItem<MessageOnTable> treeItem = param.getValue();
                MessageOnTable emp = treeItem.getValue();
                SimpleBooleanProperty booleanProp= new SimpleBooleanProperty(emp.isDelete());

                // Note: singleCol.setOnEditCommit(): Not work for
                // CheckBoxTreeTableCell.
                // When "Single?" column change.
                booleanProp.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue,
                                        Boolean newValue) {
                        emp.setDelete(newValue);
                    }
                });
                return booleanProp;
            }
        });

        deleteCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn<MessageOnTable,Boolean>,TreeTableCell<MessageOnTable,Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public TreeTableCell<MessageOnTable,Boolean> call(TreeTableColumn<MessageOnTable,Boolean> p ) {
                CheckBoxTreeTableCell<MessageOnTable,Boolean> cell = new CheckBoxTreeTableCell<MessageOnTable,Boolean>();
                cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                return cell;
            }
        });

        treeTableView.getColumns().addAll(senderCol, topicCol, contentsCol, deleteCol);
```

Comment: I cannot make any sense from your question. What is your code doing? What should it do? Please also include a [minimum example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove:

```
deleteCol.setCellValueFactory(
    new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<MessageOnTable, Boolean>("delete"));
```

Just need this line:

```
deleteCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback ....
```